# Drivers written to Access internet through AT Command Based Devices

Tags: networking, wireless, usb

USB dongles, GSM ICs use "AT" commands for configuration as well as to control their operation. Such commands have the ability to control power as well as send SMS, connect to internet via LTE,GPRS or 3G and even reset the devices and take calls. I also must mention that the only way to control such devices is via "AT" commands.

"AT" command standard have have about 10 - 15 universal commands and some devices have an added set of commands to allow connections to the internet. Below are few of such actions possible,

1. Making a connection to SSL or non SSL servers.
2. Sending data to a port in the server once the connection is active.
3. closing connections.

I believe (correct me if I am wrong) that one AT command corresponds to one of the above tasks.

I am interested in writing a driver in C for GNU/linux system  which can interpret and serve PCs internet needs via AT commands. This software must let the PC "see" it self as a "way out" perhaps like an ethernet connection. This is what most dongle softwares do.  They have usually two COM ports running at high speed. One COM port is controlled by the USB dongles default software and the other is used to send/receive data.

I would appreciate if someone can explain me how I can develop a "fake" ethernet connection or make the PC "see" a way out using this driver software. The driver software will need to "drive" the GSM IC or a USB dongle to send/receive data. This project for educational purposes therefore, I am not interested in installing a binary software and getting my dongle to work.

I would also so much appreciate if someone can relate to an open source project similar to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### hardware side: talking to GSM hardware

There seem to be several people using a "SIM900 GPRS module" to connect to web servers using AT commands.
Is this close enough to what you are looking for?

- ["FTP HTTP AT Commands User Guide"](http://www.reyax.com/Module/GSM/SIM900D/AN_SIM900_FTP_HTTP_AT_COMMANDS_USER_GUIDE_beta_V1.00.pdf)
- ["SIM900GSM Arduino library"](https://github.com/Mohammed90/SIM900GSM)
- ["Arduino Forum: POST HTTP with AT Commands"](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=116867.0)
- ["POST HTTP command to update data into web server using GPRS"](http://www.edaboard.com/thread126547.html)
- ["Sim900 AT commands + HTTP Get Request."](http://www.dsscircuits.com/forum/index.php?topic=82.0)
- ["AT command for HTTP functions"](http://m2msupport.net/m2msupport/at-command-for-http-functions-for-remote-server-data-access/)

EDIT:

### application side: talking to normal, unmodified Linux applications

It sounds like you want software like Firefox on your Linux computer to work normally, without any changes to the Firefox application itself, "as if" the PC is plugged into a standard Ethernet cable to the Internet.

So your software needs to be a device driver that "looks like" other Ethernet or WiFi device drivers on the application side, but on the hardware side routes data through a USB or other serial port to the GSM/GPRS hardware.

Could you fork some standard Ethernet device driver or Wifi device driver, and then replace the section that talks to its specific Ethernet card hardware, with a section that talks to your specific GSM/GPRS hardware?

Entire books could be and have been written on writing Linux device drivers;
and many Linux device drivers are open source software:

- Alessandro Rubini & Jonathan Corbet. [Linux Device Drivers, 2nd Edition. Chapter 14: Network Drivers](http://www.xml.com/ldd/chapter/book/ch14.html) and [Linux Device Drivers, 3rd Edition. Chapter 17: Network Drivers](https://lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch17.pdf).
- [Linux Kernel – Network device driver programming](http://free-electrons.com/doc/network-drivers-lab.pdf)
- Bhaskaran. [Writing a Network device driver - Part 1](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/LG/issue93/bhaskaran.html)
- Mohan Lal Jangir. [Writing Network Device Drivers for Linux.](http://linuxgazette.net/156/jangir.html)
- [Introduction to device drivers - Part 2 - Ethernet drivers](http://development.syllable.org/documentation/drivers/introduction/part-2.html)
- P. Raghavan, Amol Lad, Sriram Neelakandan. [Embedded Linux System Design and Development](https://books.google.com/books?id=sTDHUr4eGYIC). Section 5.2: Ethernet Driver.
- [StackOverflow: How should I get started on writing device drivers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222763/how-should-i-get-started-on-writing-device-drivers)
- [eLinux: Device drivers](http://elinux.org/Device_drivers)

For your particular application, it may be easier for you to write a normal user-space program,
and set up [TUN/TAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TUN/TAP) virtual network kernel devices to deliver packets from Firefox and other applications to your user-space program.

For questions about writing such device drivers,
since those device drivers work the same for all Linux systems (not just Ubuntu),
you may get a better response at more relevant sites such as https://unix.stackexchange.com/ , https://serverfault.com/, https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ , https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/ , etc.

Comment: I am happy you directed me to a SIM product. I often incorporate  SIM908 in my microcontroller projects applications to obtain internet connectivity. But I want to do this for a linux system. 
I can deliver one applications requirements using AT commands but my requirement is to provide the already implemented universal platform (probably fake an ethernet connection)  using the SIM908 or a dongle; a device that understands AT commands.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your edit section covers everything. This indeed is very complex. yes I believe I can folk an existing project but still I got to pick up on the knowledge first. I will try the valuable sources attached. Thank You again.